# Trying to copy files from one directory to other based on filename part using batch script

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PATH1=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\a\
SET PATH2=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\b\

PUSHD %PATH1%

for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "BESTPOST_Reporting_*_*.txt"') do (XCOPY %%a %%b %PATH2% /Y)


popd
```

It gives me the following error when I run it through commandline:
**"The syntax of the command is incorrect"**

Any suggestions?

Comment: `dir /b` only produces one token, so I'm pretty sure `%%b` will be the empty string.  What do you expect to see in `%%b`?  Also, can you confirm that the `dir` statement produces the expected output when used outside of `for`?

Answer (score 0):

Start with next code to see `for` loop effect(s):

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "PATH1=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\a"
SET "PATH2=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\b"

PUSHD %PATH1%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "BESTPOST_Reporting_*_*.txt"') do echo %%~a

popd
```

Then you could replace `echo %%~a` command with `echo xcopy "%%~a" "%path2%\%%~a" /Y` and eventually (no sooner than debugged) with

`xcopy "%%~a" "%path2%\%%~a" /Y`

**However**, all the task could be accomplished with

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "PATH1=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\a"
SET "PATH2=C:\Users\Honey\Desktop\b"

PUSHD %PATH2%

Copy /B /Y "%PATH1%\BESTPOST_Reporting_*_*.txt"

popd
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~a` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)